# помогите исправить ошибку в telebot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

попробовал написать кнопки для оценивания ответа администратора: [image: кнопки оценивания ответа]

код:

```
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
butt90 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='good')
butt91 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data='bad')
markup.add(butt90, butt91)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                file = open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'rw')
                file.write('good!!') #  
                file.close()
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                file = open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'rw')
                file.write('bad!!') # 
                file.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
```

и создал тот же файл likes.txt. нажимаю кнопку оценить и начинается загрузка на кнопке, но в файл ничего не вписывается. помогите пожалуйста подсказать в чем ошибка? ( в командную строку никакие ошибки не пишутся и бот после нажатий на кнопки работает дальше)

я поэкперементировал и получился вот такой код:

```
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == 'good':
            with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write('good!!') # 

        elif call.data == 'bad':
            with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'w') as f:
                f.write('bad!!') #
```

все работает также хорошо, но также не записывается в файл likes слова

Сейчас у меня бот хорошо заработал и всё что требовалось работает!
если у вас возникла такая же проблема, то:

1. Проверьте, нету ли в коде `bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True) def callback_inline(call)` который не используется, или конфликтует со вторым `bot.callback_query_handler`.
2. возможно что то написали не правильно, перечитайте код и поймите, всё ли написано верно.
3. или же почитайте комментарии под вопросом и посмотрите какая у меня была ошибка.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: В `callback_inline` добавьте вывод `call.message` и `call.data` (типа `print(call.message, call.data)`). Вам нужно понять что приходит в функцию и что с этим делает ваш код. PS. с файлом лучше работать через `with`: `with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'rw') as f:` `f.write('good!!') # `

Comment: @gil9red, всё равно не понял как это делается :(
я новичок в этом, не совсем понял как написать способ с with...

Comment: Если новичок, то читайте книги/статьи по языку. Просто добавьте `print` в код и при работе с ботом смотрите в консоли скрипта ожидаемые сообщения из `print`. Если не поняли про `with` то погуглите как используется, но я уже написал как, просто скопировать в код: `with open ...` на одной строке, а `f.write...` на следующей, с добавлением отступа, чтобы было как например в условиях

Comment: @gil9red, я поэкперементировал и получился вот такой код:
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
 if call.message:
  if call.data == 'good':
   with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'rw') as f:
    f.write('good!!') # 
   try:
    f.write('good!!') # 
   finally:
    f.close()
  elif call.data == 'bad':
   with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'rw') as f:
    f.write('bad!!') # 
   try:
    f.write('bad!!') # 
   finally:
    f.close()
все работает также хорошо, но также не записывается в файл likes слова

Comment: Вы молодец, что сами написали, но добавьте, пожалуйста, в сам вопрос, под первым кодом. В комментарии код нечитаемый :)

Comment: @gil9red, готово

Comment: Убрал try/finally с `close`, т.к. `with` сам такое же делает, т.е. закрывает файл. И оставил открытие файла только как `w`, т.к. только оно используется. Смотрите, строкой выше `if call.message:` добавьте `print(type(call.message), call.message, type(call.data), call.data)` и смотрите какое значение там при работе бота, в консоли будет показано. Убедитесь, что оно совпадает с тем, что у вас в условии, если нужно, то явно в `print` напишите те условия, типа: `print(call.data, call.data == 'good', call.data == 'bad')`. Это самый простой способ отладки программы

Comment: сделал так как вы сказали, https://imgur.com/a/i6NZMj6
в консоли ошибок нет https://imgur.com/a/LpjZxHS
но в файл также не записывается...не знаю что я не так делаю

Comment: здравствуйте, Вы пробовали принтом посмотреть, что вообще лежит в call.data?

Comment: Здравствуйте! я пробовал но в консоль вообще ничего не приходило. сейчас я попробовал сделать всё с нуля и вот что вышло @gil9red : https://radikal.ru/video/DrAD1CpTd9t там я написал всё как сказал gil9red и всё отлично даже работает, только скорее всего проблемы связаны с основным ботом, и он не совместимо работает с данными кнопками. также вышел json формат в консоль

Comment: уберите все лишнее и попробуйте выводить только call.data, содержание при выводе отправьте сюда, разберемся в чем там проблема

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RjFgMib

Comment: попробуйте объявить метод для записи, что-то вроде:
```def write_mark_to_file(mark):
    with open('C://tgbot/likes.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(mark + '!!')```
Таким образом вы избежите дублирования кода - он станет более читабельным. Второе, что Вам принесет такой подход - не нужно осуществлять следующую проверку:
```if call.data == 'good':
 ...
elif call.data == 'bad':
...```
В вашем случае они бесполезны, Вы осуществляете одни и те же действия, меняется лишь содержание того, что Вы кладете в файл.

Comment: спасибо вам всем за помощь! вы очень сильно мне помогли! но проблему сделал сам-же я... я не убрал старый метод @bot.callback_query_handler и в коде было 2 таких метода, 1 из них в боте не использовался, и я просто попробовал убрать неиспользованный метод и всё ЗАРАБОТАЛО! извините если потянул время и потревожил ваше время, но gil9red мне очень помог! спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @TerenceHart, хорошо, что вы разобрались. Оформите сами ответ, добавьте что вам помогло. Желательно с кодом :)